# Move a Project Collection of TFS to another disk

Tags: tfs

I am having short place in the disk where my TFS server is installed and i want to move some projet collections to a different disk on network where there is more place, can i proceed this moving without reinstalling again TFS and detach the collection and attach it again ?

Comment: Note that your project collections aren't "on disk". They are in the database. If you want to move something, you'll have to move the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS installation is server specific.  On that server you will have your collection db named: Tfs_XXX along with that you have your warehouse, sharepoint, reporting and configuration tables.

I think what you are asking is "Can I have X team project on server X and Y team project on server Y but still only have one installation of TFS to manage them both" or "Can I have X Collection on server X and Y collection on server Y but still only have one installation of TFS to manage them both"

The answer to both questions is no.  Server has collections - Collections have Team Projects.

You will need to have a separate installation if you want to move your Collection or Team Project to another server.

What our team does is run TFS in a Virtual Image so that we can dynamically expand the drive as needed.  You may want to consider a similar solution assuming you have the hardware to do it.  Alternatively, you can ofcourse expand your drive or setup tasks to Shrink your db.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I achieved this by moving certain Project Collection SQL databases to a different SQL Server Instance while leaving the config database on the original server.

Basically you need to configure a second SQL Server Instance to allow TFS databases on it, then move the database to that server, then reconfigure the project collection to point to the second SQL Server instance.

See exactly how to do it in this blog post: http://healthedev.blogspot.com/2011/12/move-tfs-2010-project-collection.html